# Column in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have to extract two columns of a txt file and I want to put them in a matrix. Here is my code:

```
fichier="fichier_position_2_test.txt"
file = open(fichier, "rb")

B=[]
for ligne in file:
   ligne = ligne.split(' ')
   B = array([(ligne[1]),(ligne[2])])
print B
print B[5,0]
```

It prints an error:

```
index 5 i out of bound.
```

It seems that I don't get a matrix.

Here is an extract of the  txt file:

```
0 0 8e-06 -5.2e-05
0.001 0 8e-06 -5.2e-05
0.002 -4.47168e-09 7.27762e-06 -5.20635e-05
0.003 -4.44939e-08 6.30378e-06 -5.23847e-05
0.004 -1.23794e-07 5.10395e-06 -5.29779e-05
0.005 -2.50143e-07 3.71246e-06 -5.38641e-05
0.006 -4.34734e-07 2.17422e-06 -5.50617e-05
0.007 -6.81754e-07 5.4552e-07 -5.65878e-05
0.008 -9.9514e-07 -1.1068e-06 -5.84496e-05
0.009 -1.38676e-06 -2.70711e-06 -6.06325e-05
0.01 -1.87106e-06 -4.17564e-06 -6.30971e-05
0.011 -2.43793e-06 -5.44811e-06 -6.58122e-05
0.012 -3.06817e-06 -6.48317e-06 -6.87451e-05
0.013 -3.74877e-06 -7.28368e-06 -7.18592e-05
0.014 -4.47468e-06 -7.85783e-06 -7.51507e-05
0.015 -5.25353e-06 -8.18399e-06 -7.86796e-05
0.016 -6.0518e-06 -8.2083e-06 -8.24502e-05
0.017 -6.85579e-06 -7.88863e-06 -8.63925e-05
0.018 -7.67301e-06 -7.23934e-06 -9.04763e-05
0.019 -8.52122e-06 -6.26409e-06 -9.48178e-05
0.02 -9.41844e-06 -5.0028e-06 -9.94931e-05
0.021 -1.03442e-05 -3.51387e-06 -0.000104472
0.022 -1.13166e-05 -1.8649e-06 -0.000109719
0.023 -1.22989e-05 -1.29706e-07 -0.000115202
0.024 -1.32971e-05 1.61182e-06 -0.000120907
0.025 -1.43445e-05 3.27188e-06 -0.000126905
0.026 -1.54456e-05 4.76694e-06 -0.000133113
0.027 -1.65588e-05 6.08799e-06 -0.000139468
0.028 -1.7704e-05 7.24749e-06 -0.000145865
0.029 -1.88498e-05 8.22123e-06 -0.000152123
0.03 -1.99753e-05 9.07204e-06 -0.000158219
0.031 -2.10926e-05 9.85231e-06 -0.000164232
0.032 -2.22015e-05 1.05878e-05 -0.000170185
0.033 -2.33038e-05 1.13142e-05 -0.000176124
0.034 -2.44061e-05 1.20406e-05 -0.000182063
0.035 -2.55085e-05 1.2767e-05 -0.000188002
0.036 -2.66108e-05 1.34934e-05 -0.000193941
0.037 -2.77132e-05 1.42198e-05 -0.000199879
0.038 -2.88155e-05 1.49462e-05 -0.000205818
0.039 -2.99178e-05 1.56726e-05 -0.000211757
0.04 -3.10202e-05 1.6399e-05 -0.000217696
0.041 -3.21225e-05 1.71254e-05 -0.000223635
0.042 -3.32248e-05 1.78518e-05 -0.000229573
0.043 -3.43272e-05 1.85782e-05 -0.000235512
0.044 -3.54295e-05 1.93046e-05 -0.000241451
0.045 -3.65319e-05 2.00311e-05 -0.00024739
0.046 -3.76342e-05 2.07575e-05 -0.000253329
0.047 -3.87365e-05 2.14839e-05 -0.000259267
0.048 -3.98389e-05 2.22103e-05 -0.000265206
0.049 -4.09412e-05 2.29367e-05 -0.000271145
0.05 -4.20436e-05 2.36631e-05 -0.000277084
0.051 -4.31459e-05 2.43895e-05 -0.000283023
0.052 -4.42482e-05 2.51159e-05 -0.000288961
0.053 -4.53506e-05 2.58423e-05 -0.0002949
0.054 -4.64529e-05 2.65687e-05 -0.000300839
0.055 -4.75553e-05 2.72951e-05 -0.000306778
0.056 -4.86576e-05 2.80215e-05 -0.000312716
0.057 -4.97599e-05 2.87479e-05 -0.000318655
0.058 -5.08623e-05 2.94743e-05 -0.000324594
0.059 -5.19646e-05 3.02008e-05 -0.000330533
0.06 -5.30669e-05 3.09272e-05 -0.000336472
0.061 -5.41693e-05 3.16536e-05 -0.00034241
0.062 -5.52716e-05 3.238e-05 -0.000348349
0.063 -5.6374e-05 3.31064e-05 -0.000354288
0.064 -5.74763e-05 3.38328e-05 -0.000360227
0.065 -5.85786e-05 3.45592e-05 -0.000366166
0.066 -5.9681e-05 3.52856e-05 -0.000372104
0.067 -6.07833e-05 3.6012e-05 -0.000378043
0.068 -6.18857e-05 3.67384e-05 -0.000383982
0.069 -6.2988e-05 3.74648e-05 -0.000389921
0.07 -6.40903e-05 3.81912e-05 -0.00039586
0.071 -6.51927e-05 3.89176e-05 -0.000401798
0.072 -6.6295e-05 3.96441e-05 -0.000407737
0.073 -6.73974e-05 4.03705e-05 -0.000413676
0.074 -6.84997e-05 4.10969e-05 -0.000419615
0.075 -6.9602e-05 4.18233e-05 -0.000425554
0.076 -7.07044e-05 4.25497e-05 -0.000431492
0.077 -7.18067e-05 4.32761e-05 -0.000437431
0.078 -7.2909e-05 4.40025e-05 -0.00044337
0.079 -7.40114e-05 4.47289e-05 -0.000449309
0.08 -7.51137e-05 4.54553e-05 -0.000455248
0.081 -7.62161e-05 4.61817e-05 -0.000461186
0.082 -7.73184e-05 4.69081e-05 -0.000467125
0.083 -7.84207e-05 4.76345e-05 -0.000473064
0.084 -7.95231e-05 4.83609e-05 -0.000479003
0.085 -8.06254e-05 4.90873e-05 -0.000484942
0.086 -8.17278e-05 4.98138e-05 -0.00049088
0.087 -8.28301e-05 5.05402e-05 -0.000496819
0.088 -8.39324e-05 5.12666e-05 -0.000502758
0.089 -8.50348e-05 5.1993e-05 -0.000508697
0.09 -8.61371e-05 5.27194e-05 -0.000514636
0.091 -8.72395e-05 5.34458e-05 -0.000520574
0.092 -8.83418e-05 5.41722e-05 -0.000526513
0.093 -8.94441e-05 5.48986e-05 -0.000532452
0.094 -9.05465e-05 5.5625e-05 -0.000538391
0.095 -9.16488e-05 5.63514e-05 -0.00054433
0.096 -9.27511e-05 5.70778e-05 -0.000550268
0.097 -9.38535e-05 5.78042e-05 -0.000556207
0.098 -9.49558e-05 5.85306e-05 -0.000562146
0.099 -9.60582e-05 5.92571e-05 -0.000568085
0.1 -9.71605e-05 5.99835e-05 -0.000574024
0.101 -9.82628e-05 6.07099e-05 -0.000579962
0.102 -9.93652e-05 6.14363e-05 -0.000585901
0.103 -0.000100468 6.21627e-05 -0.00059184
0.104 -0.00010157 6.28891e-05 -0.000597779
0.105 -0.000102672 6.36155e-05 -0.000603718
0.106 -0.000103775 6.43419e-05 -0.000609656
0.107 -0.000104877 6.50683e-05 -0.000615595
0.108 -0.000105979 6.57947e-05 -0.000621534
0.109 -0.000107082 6.65211e-05 -0.000627473
0.11 -0.000108184 6.72475e-05 -0.000633412
0.111 -0.000109286 6.79739e-05 -0.00063935
0.112 -0.000110389 6.87003e-05 -0.000645289
0.113 -0.000111491 6.94268e-05 -0.000651228
0.114 -0.000112593 7.01532e-05 -0.000657167
0.115 -0.000113696 7.08796e-05 -0.000663105
0.116 -0.000114798 7.1606e-05 -0.000669044
0.117 -0.0001159 7.23324e-05 -0.000674983
0.118 -0.000117003 7.30588e-05 -0.000680922
0.119 -0.000118105 7.37852e-05 -0.000686861
0.12 -0.000119207 7.45116e-05 -0.000692799
0.121 -0.00012031 7.5238e-05 -0.000698738
0.122 -0.000121412 7.59644e-05 -0.000704677
0.123 -0.000122514 7.66908e-05 -0.000710616
0.124 -0.000123617 7.74172e-05 -0.000716555
0.125 -0.000124719 7.81436e-05 -0.000722493
0.126 -0.000125821 7.887e-05 -0.000728432
0.127 -0.000126924 7.95965e-05 -0.000734371
0.128 -0.000128026 8.03229e-05 -0.00074031
0.129 -0.000129128 8.10493e-05 -0.000746249
0.13 -0.000130231 8.17757e-05 -0.000752187
0.131 -0.000131333 8.25021e-05 -0.000758126
0.132 -0.000132435 8.32285e-05 -0.000764065
0.133 -0.000133538 8.39549e-05 -0.000770004
0.134 -0.00013464 8.46813e-05 -0.000775943
0.135 -0.000135742 8.54077e-05 -0.000781881
0.136 -0.000136845 8.61341e-05 -0.00078782
0.137 -0.000137947 8.68605e-05 -0.000793759
0.138 -0.000139049 8.75869e-05 -0.000799698
0.139 -0.000140152 8.83133e-05 -0.000805637
0.14 -0.000141254 8.90398e-05 -0.000811575
0.141 -0.000142356 8.97662e-05 -0.000817514
0.142 -0.000143459 9.04926e-05 -0.000823453
0.143 -0.000144561 9.1219e-05 -0.000829392
0.144 -0.000145663 9.19454e-05 -0.000835331
0.145 -0.000146766 9.26718e-05 -0.000841269
0.146 -0.000147868 9.33982e-05 -0.000847208
0.147 -0.00014897 9.41246e-05 -0.000853147
0.148 -0.000150073 9.4851e-05 -0.000859086
0.149 -0.000151175 9.55774e-05 -0.000865025
0.15 -0.000152277 9.63038e-05 -0.000870963
0.151 -0.00015338 9.70302e-05 -0.000876902
0.152 -0.000154482 9.77566e-05 -0.000882841
0.153 -0.000155584 9.8483e-05 -0.00088878
0.154 -0.000156687 9.92095e-05 -0.000894719
0.155 -0.000157789 9.99359e-05 -0.000900657
0.156 -0.000158891 0.000100662 -0.000906596
0.157 -0.000159994 0.000101389 -0.000912535
0.158 -0.000161096 0.000102115 -0.000918474
0.159 -0.000162198 0.000102841 -0.000924413
0.16 -0.000163301 0.000103568 -0.000930351
0.161 -0.000164403 0.000104294 -0.00093629
0.162 -0.000165506 0.000105021 -0.000942229
0.163 -0.000166608 0.000105747 -0.000948168
0.164 -0.00016771 0.000106474 -0.000954107
0.165 -0.000168813 0.0001072 -0.000960045
0.166 -0.000169915 0.000107926 -0.000965984
0.167 -0.000171017 0.000108653 -0.000971923
0.168 -0.00017212 0.000109379 -0.000977862
0.169 -0.000173222 0.000110106 -0.0009838
0.17 -0.000174324 0.000110832 -0.000989739
0.171 -0.000175427 0.000111558 -0.000995678
0.172 -0.000176529 0.000112285 -0.00100162
0.173 -0.000177631 0.000113011 -0.00100756
0.174 -0.000178734 0.000113738 -0.00101349
0.175 -0.000179836 0.000114464 -0.00101943
0.176 -0.000180938 0.00011519 -0.00102537
0.177 -0.000182041 0.000115917 -0.00103131
0.178 -0.000183143 0.000116643 -0.00103725
0.179 -0.000184245 0.00011737 -0.00104319
0.18 -0.000185348 0.000118096 -0.00104913
0.181 -0.00018645 0.000118822 -0.00105507
0.182 -0.000187552 0.000119549 -0.001061
0.183 -0.000188655 0.000120275 -0.00106694
0.184 -0.000189757 0.000121002 -0.00107288
0.185 -0.000190859 0.000121728 -0.00107882
0.186 -0.000191962 0.000122454 -0.00108476
0.187 -0.000193064 0.000123181 -0.0010907
0.188 -0.000194166 0.000123907 -0.00109664
0.189 -0.000195269 0.000124634 -0.00110258
0.19 -0.000196371 0.00012536 -0.00110852
0.191 -0.000197473 0.000126087 -0.00111445
0.192 -0.000198576 0.000126813 -0.00112039
0.193 -0.000199678 0.000127539 -0.00112633
0.194 -0.00020078 0.000128266 -0.00113227
0.195 -0.000201883 0.000128992 -0.00113821
0.196 -0.000202985 0.000129719 -0.00114415
0.197 -0.000204087 0.000130445 -0.00115009
0.198 -0.00020519 0.000131171 -0.00115603
0.199 -0.000206292 0.000131898 -0.00116196
0.2 -0.000207394 0.000132624 -0.0011679
0.201 -0.000208497 0.000133351 -0.00117384
0.202 -0.000209599 0.000134077 -0.00117978
0.203 -0.000210701 0.000134803 -0.00118572
0.204 -0.000211804 0.00013553 -0.00119166
0.205 -0.000212906 0.000136256 -0.0011976
0.206 -0.000214008 0.000136983 -0.00120354
0.207 -0.000215111 0.000137709 -0.00120947
0.208 -0.000216213 0.000138435 -0.00121541
0.209 -0.000217315 0.000139162 -0.00122135
0.21 -0.000218418 0.000139888 -0.00122729
0.211 -0.00021952 0.000140615 -0.00123323
0.212 -0.000220622 0.000141341 -0.00123917
0.213 -0.000221725 0.000142067 -0.00124511
0.214 -0.000222827 0.000142794 -0.00125105
0.215 -0.000223929 0.00014352 -0.00125699
0.216 -0.000225032 0.000144247 -0.00126292
0.217 -0.000226134 0.000144973 -0.00126886
0.218 -0.000227236 0.0001457 -0.0012748
0.219 -0.000228339 0.000146426 -0.00128074
0.22 -0.000229441 0.000147152 -0.00128668
0.221 -0.000230544 0.000147879 -0.00129262
0.222 -0.000231646 0.000148605 -0.00129856
0.223 -0.000232748 0.000149332 -0.0013045
0.224 -0.000233851 0.000150058 -0.00131043
0.225 -0.000234953 0.000150784 -0.00131637
0.226 -0.000236055 0.000151511 -0.00132231
0.227 -0.000237158 0.000152237 -0.00132825
0.228 -0.00023826 0.000152964 -0.00133419
0.229 -0.000239362 0.00015369 -0.00134013
0.23 -0.000240465 0.000154416 -0.00134607
0.231 -0.000241567 0.000155143 -0.00135201
0.232 -0.000242669 0.000155869 -0.00135794
0.233 -0.000243772 0.000156596 -0.00136388
0.234 -0.000244874 0.000157322 -0.00136982
0.235 -0.000245976 0.000158048 -0.00137576
0.236 -0.000247079 0.000158775 -0.0013817
0.237 -0.000248181 0.000159501 -0.00138764
0.238 -0.000249283 0.000160228 -0.00139358
0.239 -0.000250386 0.000160954 -0.00139952
0.24 -0.000251488 0.00016168 -0.00140546
0.241 -0.00025259 0.000162407 -0.00141139
0.242 -0.000253693 0.000163133 -0.00141733
0.243 -0.000254795 0.00016386 -0.00142327
0.244 -0.000255897 0.000164586 -0.00142921
0.245 -0.000257 0.000165313 -0.00143515
0.246 -0.000258102 0.000166039 -0.00144109
0.247 -0.000259204 0.000166765 -0.00144703
0.248 -0.000260307 0.000167492 -0.00145297
0.249 -0.000261409 0.000168218 -0.0014589
0.25 -0.000262511 0.000168945 -0.00146484
0.251 -0.000263614 0.000169671 -0.00147078
0.252 -0.000264716 0.000170397 -0.00147672
0.253 -0.000265818 0.000171124 -0.00148266
0.254 -0.000266921 0.00017185 -0.0014886
0.255 -0.000268023 0.000172577 -0.00149454
0.256 -0.000269125 0.000173303 -0.00150048
0.257 -0.000270228 0.000174029 -0.00150641
0.258 -0.00027133 0.000174756 -0.00151235
0.259 -0.000272432 0.000175482 -0.00151829
0.26 -0.000273535 0.000176209 -0.00152423
0.261 -0.000274637 0.000176935 -0.00153017
0.262 -0.000275739 0.000177661 -0.00153611
0.263 -0.000276842 0.000178388 -0.00154205
0.264 -0.000277944 0.000179114 -0.00154799
0.265 -0.000279046 0.000179841 -0.00155392
0.266 -0.000280149 0.000180567 -0.00155986
0.267 -0.000281251 0.000181293 -0.0015658
0.268 -0.000282353 0.00018202 -0.00157174
0.269 -0.000283456 0.000182746 -0.00157768
0.27 -0.000284558 0.000183473 -0.00158362
0.271 -0.00028566 0.000184199 -0.00158956
0.272 -0.000286763 0.000184926 -0.0015955
0.273 -0.000287865 0.000185652 -0.00160144
0.274 -0.000288967 0.000186378 -0.00160737
0.275 -0.00029007 0.000187105 -0.00161331
0.276 -0.000291172 0.000187831 -0.00161925
0.277 -0.000292274 0.000188558 -0.00162519
0.278 -0.000293377 0.000189284 -0.00163113
0.279 -0.000294479 0.00019001 -0.00163707
0.28 -0.000295581 0.000190737 -0.00164301
0.281 -0.000296684 0.000191463 -0.00164895
0.282 -0.000297786 0.00019219 -0.00165488
0.283 -0.000298889 0.000192916 -0.00166082
0.284 -0.000299991 0.000193642 -0.00166676
0.285 -0.000301093 0.000194369 -0.0016727
0.286 -0.000302196 0.000195095 -0.00167864
0.287 -0.000303298 0.000195822 -0.00168458
0.288 -0.0003044 0.000196548 -0.00169052
0.289 -0.000305503 0.000197274 -0.00169646
0.29 -0.000306605 0.000198001 -0.00170239
0.291 -0.000307707 0.000198727 -0.00170833
0.292 -0.00030881 0.000199454 -0.00171427
0.293 -0.000309912 0.00020018 -0.00172021
0.294 -0.000311014 0.000200906 -0.00172615
0.295 -0.000312117 0.000201633 -0.00173209
0.296 -0.000313219 0.000202359 -0.00173803
0.297 -0.000314321 0.000203086 -0.00174397
0.298 -0.000315424 0.000203812 -0.00174991
0.299 -0.000316526 0.000204539 -0.00175584
0.3 -0.000317628 0.000205265 -0.00176178
0.301 -0.000318731 0.000205991 -0.00176772
0.302 -0.000319833 0.000206718 -0.00177366
0.303 -0.000320935 0.000207444 -0.0017796
0.304 -0.000322038 0.000208171 -0.00178554
0.305 -0.00032314 0.000208897 -0.00179148
0.306 -0.000324242 0.000209623 -0.00179742
0.307 -0.000325345 0.00021035 -0.00180335
0.308 -0.000326447 0.000211076 -0.00180929
0.309 -0.000327549 0.000211803 -0.00181523
0.31 -0.000328652 0.000212529 -0.00182117
0.311 -0.000329754 0.000213255 -0.00182711
0.312 -0.000330856 0.000213982 -0.00183305
0.313 -0.000331959 0.000214708 -0.00183899
0.314 -0.000333061 0.000215435 -0.00184493
0.315 -0.000334163 0.000216161 -0.00185086
0.316 -0.000335266 0.000216887 -0.0018568
0.317 -0.000336368 0.000217614 -0.00186274
0.318 -0.00033747 0.00021834 -0.00186868
0.319 -0.000338573 0.000219067 -0.00187462
0.32 -0.000339675 0.000219793 -0.00188056
0.321 -0.000340777 0.000220519 -0.0018865
0.322 -0.00034188 0.000221246 -0.00189244
0.323 -0.000342982 0.000221972 -0.00189838
0.324 -0.000344084 0.000222699 -0.00190431
0.325 -0.000345187 0.000223425 -0.00191025
0.326 -0.000346289 0.000224152 -0.00191619
0.327 -0.000347391 0.000224878 -0.00192213
0.328 -0.000348494 0.000225604 -0.00192807
0.329 -0.000349596 0.000226331 -0.00193401
0.33 -0.000350698 0.000227057 -0.00193995
0.331 -0.000351801 0.000227784 -0.00194589
0.332 -0.000352903 0.00022851 -0.00195182
0.333 -0.000354005 0.000229236 -0.00195776
0.334 -0.000355108 0.000229963 -0.0019637
0.335 -0.00035621 0.000230689 -0.00196964
0.336 -0.000357312 0.000231416 -0.00197558
0.337 -0.000358415 0.000232142 -0.00198152
0.338 -0.000359517 0.000232868 -0.00198746
0.339 -0.000360619 0.000233595 -0.0019934
0.34 -0.000361722 0.000234321 -0.00199933
0.341 -0.000362824 0.000235048 -0.00200527
0.342 -0.000363927 0.000235774 -0.00201121
0.343 -0.000365029 0.0002365 -0.00201715
0.344 -0.000366131 0.000237227 -0.00202309
0.345 -0.000367234 0.000237953 -0.00202903
0.346 -0.000368336 0.00023868 -0.00203497
0.347 -0.000369438 0.000239406 -0.00204091
0.348 -0.000370541 0.000240132 -0.00204685
0.349 -0.000371643 0.000240859 -0.00205278
0.35 -0.000372745 0.000241585 -0.00205872
0.351 -0.000373848 0.000242312 -0.00206466
0.352 -0.00037495 0.000243038 -0.0020706
0.353 -0.000376052 0.000243765 -0.00207654
0.354 -0.000377155 0.000244491 -0.00208248
0.355 -0.000378257 0.000245217 -0.00208842
0.356 -0.000379359 0.000245944 -0.00209436
0.357 -0.000380462 0.00024667 -0.00210029
0.358 -0.000381564 0.000247397 -0.00210623
0.359 -0.000382666 0.000248123 -0.00211217
0.36 -0.000383769 0.000248849 -0.00211811
0.361 -0.000384871 0.000249576 -0.00212405
0.362 -0.000385973 0.000250302 -0.00212999
0.363 -0.000387076 0.000251029 -0.00213593
0.364 -0.000388178 0.000251755 -0.00214187
0.365 -0.00038928 0.000252481 -0.0021478
0.366 -0.000390383 0.000253208 -0.00215374
0.367 -0.000391485 0.000253934 -0.00215968
0.368 -0.000392587 0.000254661 -0.00216562
0.369 -0.00039369 0.000255387 -0.00217156
0.37 -0.000394792 0.000256113 -0.0021775
0.371 -0.000395894 0.00025684 -0.00218344
0.372 -0.000396997 0.000257566 -0.00218938
0.373 -0.000398099 0.000258293 -0.00219531
0.374 -0.000399201 0.000259019 -0.00220125
0.375 -0.000400304 0.000259745 -0.00220719
0.376 -0.000401406 0.000260472 -0.00221313
0.377 -0.000402508 0.000261198 -0.00221907
0.378 -0.000403611 0.000261925 -0.00222501
0.379 -0.000404713 0.000262651 -0.00223095
0.38 -0.000405815 0.000263378 -0.00223689
0.381 -0.000406918 0.000264104 -0.00224283
0.382 -0.00040802 0.00026483 -0.00224876
0.383 -0.000409122 0.000265557 -0.0022547
0.384 -0.000410225 0.000266283 -0.00226064
0.385 -0.000411327 0.00026701 -0.00226658
0.386 -0.000412429 0.000267736 -0.00227252
0.387 -0.000413532 0.000268462 -0.00227846
0.388 -0.000414634 0.000269189 -0.0022844
0.389 -0.000415736 0.000269915 -0.00229034
0.39 -0.000416839 0.000270642 -0.00229627
0.391 -0.000417941 0.000271368 -0.00230221
0.392 -0.000419043 0.000272094 -0.00230815
0.393 -0.000420146 0.000272821 -0.00231409
0.394 -0.000421248 0.000273547 -0.00232003
0.395 -0.00042235 0.000274274 -0.00232597
0.396 -0.000423453 0.000275 -0.00233191
0.397 -0.000424555 0.000275726 -0.00233785
0.398 -0.000425657 0.000276453 -0.00234378
0.399 -0.00042676 0.000277179 -0.00234972
0.4 -0.000427862 0.000277906 -0.00235566
0.401 -0.000428964 0.000278632 -0.0023616
0.402 -0.000430067 0.000279358 -0.00236754
0.403 -0.000431169 0.000280085 -0.00237348
0.404 -0.000432272 0.000280811 -0.00237942
0.405 -0.000433374 0.000281538 -0.00238536
0.406 -0.000434476 0.000282264 -0.0023913
0.407 -0.000435579 0.000282991 -0.00239723
0.408 -0.000436681 0.000283717 -0.00240317
0.409 -0.000437783 0.000284443 -0.00240911
0.41 -0.000438886 0.00028517 -0.00241505
0.411 -0.000439988 0.000285896 -0.00242099
0.412 -0.00044109 0.000286623 -0.00242693
0.413 -0.000442193 0.000287349 -0.00243287
0.414 -0.000443295 0.000288075 -0.00243881
0.415 -0.000444397 0.000288802 -0.00244474
0.416 -0.0004455 0.000289528 -0.00245068
0.417 -0.000446602 0.000290255 -0.00245662
0.418 -0.000447704 0.000290981 -0.00246256
0.419 -0.000448807 0.000291707 -0.0024685
0.42 -0.000449909 0.000292434 -0.00247444
0.421 -0.000451011 0.00029316 -0.00248038
0.422 -0.000452114 0.000293887 -0.00248632
0.423 -0.000453216 0.000294613 -0.00249225
0.424 -0.000454318 0.000295339 -0.00249819
0.425 -0.000455421 0.000296066 -0.00250413
0.426 -0.000456523 0.000296792 -0.00251007
0.427 -0.000457625 0.000297519 -0.00251601
0.428 -0.000458728 0.000298245 -0.00252195
0.429 -0.00045983 0.000298971 -0.00252789
0.43 -0.000460932 0.000299698 -0.00253383
0.431 -0.000462035 0.000300424 -0.00253977
0.432 -0.000463137 0.000301151 -0.0025457
0.433 -0.000464239 0.000301877 -0.00255164
0.434 -0.000465342 0.000302604 -0.00255758
0.435 -0.000466444 0.00030333 -0.00256352
0.436 -0.000467546 0.000304056 -0.00256946
0.437 -0.000468649 0.000304783 -0.0025754
0.438 -0.000469751 0.000305509 -0.00258134
0.439 -0.000470853 0.000306236 -0.00258728
0.44 -0.000471956 0.000306962 -0.00259321
0.441 -0.000473058 0.000307688 -0.00259915
0.442 -0.00047416 0.000308415 -0.00260509
0.443 -0.000475263 0.000309141 -0.00261103
0.444 -0.000476365 0.000309868 -0.00261697
0.445 -0.000477467 0.000310594 -0.00262291
0.446 -0.00047857 0.00031132 -0.00262885
0.447 -0.000479672 0.000312047 -0.00263479
0.448 -0.000480774 0.000312773 -0.00264072
0.449 -0.000481877 0.0003135 -0.00264666
0.45 -0.000482979 0.000314226 -0.0026526
0.451 -0.000484081 0.000314952 -0.00265854
0.452 -0.000485184 0.000315679 -0.00266448
0.453 -0.000486286 0.000316405 -0.00267042
0.454 -0.000487388 0.000317132 -0.00267636
0.455 -0.000488491 0.000317858 -0.0026823
0.456 -0.000489593 0.000318584 -0.00268824
0.457 -0.000490695 0.000319311 -0.00269417
0.458 -0.000491798 0.000320037 -0.00270011
0.459 -0.0004929 0.000320764 -0.00270605
0.46 -0.000494002 0.00032149 -0.00271199
0.461 -0.000495105 0.000322217 -0.00271793
0.462 -0.000496207 0.000322943 -0.00272387
0.463 -0.00049731 0.000323669 -0.00272981
0.464 -0.000498412 0.000324396 -0.00273575
0.465 -0.000499514 0.000325122 -0.00274168
0.466 -0.000500617 0.000325849 -0.00274762
0.467 -0.000501719 0.000326575 -0.00275356
0.468 -0.000502821 0.000327301 -0.0027595
0.469 -0.000503924 0.000328028 -0.00276544
0.47 -0.000505026 0.000328754 -0.00277138
0.471 -0.000506128 0.000329481 -0.00277732
0.472 -0.000507231 0.000330207 -0.00278326
0.473 -0.000508333 0.000330933 -0.00278919
0.474 -0.000509435 0.00033166 -0.00279513
0.475 -0.000510538 0.000332386 -0.00280107
0.476 -0.00051164 0.000333113 -0.00280701
0.477 -0.000512742 0.000333839 -0.00281295
0.478 -0.000513845 0.000334565 -0.00281889
0.479 -0.000514947 0.000335292 -0.00282483
0.48 -0.000516049 0.000336018 -0.00283077
0.481 -0.000517152 0.000336745 -0.0028367
0.482 -0.000518254 0.000337471 -0.00284264
0.483 -0.000519356 0.000338197 -0.00284858
0.484 -0.000520459 0.000338924 -0.00285452
0.485 -0.000521561 0.00033965 -0.00286046
0.486 -0.000522663 0.000340377 -0.0028664
0.487 -0.000523766 0.000341103 -0.00287234
0.488 -0.000524868 0.00034183 -0.00287828
0.489 -0.00052597 0.000342556 -0.00288422
0.49 -0.000527073 0.000343282 -0.00289015
0.491 -0.000528175 0.000344009 -0.00289609
0.492 -0.000529277 0.000344735 -0.00290203
0.493 -0.00053038 0.000345462 -0.00290797
0.494 -0.000531482 0.000346188 -0.00291391
0.495 -0.000532584 0.000346914 -0.00291985
0.496 -0.000533687 0.000347641 -0.00292579
0.497 -0.000534789 0.000348367 -0.00293173
0.498 -0.000535891 0.000349094 -0.00293766
0.499 -0.000536994 0.00034982 -0.0029436
0.5 -0.000538096 0.000350546 -0.00294954
0.501 -0.000539198 0.000351273 -0.00295548
0.502 -0.000540301 0.000351999 -0.00296142
0.503 -0.000541403 0.000352726 -0.00296736
0.504 -0.000542505 0.000353452 -0.0029733
0.505 -0.000543608 0.000354178 -0.00297924
0.506 -0.00054471 0.000354905 -0.00298517
0.507 -0.000545812 0.000355631 -0.00299111
0.508 -0.000546915 0.000356358 -0.00299705
0.509 -0.000548017 0.000357084 -0.00300299
0.51 -0.000549119 0.00035781 -0.00300893
0.511 -0.000550222 0.000358537 -0.00301487
0.512 -0.000551324 0.000359263 -0.00302081
0.513 -0.000552426 0.00035999 -0.00302675
0.514 -0.000553529 0.000360716 -0.00303269
0.515 -0.000554631 0.000361443 -0.00303862
0.516 -0.000555733 0.000362169 -0.00304456
0.517 -0.000556836 0.000362895 -0.0030505
0.518 -0.000557938 0.000363622 -0.00305644
0.519 -0.00055904 0.000364348 -0.00306238
0.52 -0.000560143 0.000365075 -0.00306832
0.521 -0.000561245 0.000365801 -0.00307426
0.522 -0.000562348 0.000366527 -0.0030802
0.523 -0.00056345 0.000367254 -0.00308613
0.524 -0.000564552 0.00036798 -0.00309207
0.525 -0.000565655 0.000368707 -0.00309801
0.526 -0.000566757 0.000369433 -0.00310395
0.527 -0.000567859 0.000370159 -0.00310989
0.528 -0.000568962 0.000370886 -0.00311583
0.529 -0.000570064 0.000371612 -0.00312177
0.53 -0.000571166 0.000372339 -0.00312771
0.531 -0.000572269 0.000373065 -0.00313364
0.532 -0.000573371 0.000373791 -0.00313958
0.533 -0.000574473 0.000374518 -0.00314552
0.534 -0.000575576 0.000375244 -0.00315146
0.535 -0.000576678 0.000375971 -0.0031574
0.536 -0.00057778 0.000376697 -0.00316334
0.537 -0.000578883 0.000377423 -0.00316928
0.538 -0.000579985 0.00037815 -0.00317522
0.539 -0.000581087 0.000378876 -0.00318116
0.54 -0.00058219 0.000379603 -0.00318709
0.541 -0.000583292 0.000380329 -0.00319303
0.542 -0.000584394 0.000381056 -0.00319897
0.543 -0.000585497 0.000381782 -0.00320491
0.544 -0.000586599 0.000382508 -0.00321085
0.545 -0.000587701 0.000383235 -0.00321679
0.546 -0.000588804 0.000383961 -0.00322273
0.547 -0.000589906 0.000384688 -0.00322867
0.548 -0.000591008 0.000385414 -0.0032346
0.549 -0.000592111 0.00038614 -0.00324054
0.55 -0.000593213 0.000386867 -0.00324648
0.551 -0.000594315 0.000387593 -0.00325242
0.552 -0.000595418 0.00038832 -0.00325836
0.553 -0.00059652 0.000389046 -0.0032643
0.554 -0.000597622 0.000389772 -0.00327024
0.555 -0.000598725 0.000390499 -0.00327618
0.556 -0.000599827 0.000391225 -0.00328211
0.557 -0.000600929 0.000391952 -0.00328805
0.558 -0.000602032 0.000392678 -0.00329399
0.559 -0.000603134 0.000393404 -0.00329993
0.56 -0.000604236 0.000394131 -0.00330587
0.561 -0.000605339 0.000394857 -0.00331181
0.562 -0.000606441 0.000395584 -0.00331775
0.563 -0.000607543 0.00039631 -0.00332369
0.564 -0.000608646 0.000397036 -0.00332963
0.565 -0.000609748 0.000397763 -0.00333556
0.566 -0.00061085 0.000398489 -0.0033415
0.567 -0.000611953 0.000399216 -0.00334744
0.568 -0.000613055 0.000399942 -0.00335338
0.569 -0.000614157 0.000400669 -0.00335932
0.57 -0.00061526 0.000401395 -0.00336526
0.571 -0.000616362 0.000402121 -0.0033712
0.572 -0.000617464 0.000402848 -0.00337714
0.573 -0.000618567 0.000403574 -0.00338307
0.574 -0.000619669 0.000404301 -0.00338901
0.575 -0.000620771 0.000405027 -0.00339495
0.576 -0.000621874 0.000405753 -0.00340089
0.577 -0.000622976 0.00040648 -0.00340683
...
```

Comment: What do you do by `print B[5,0]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the columns with index `1` and `2`, you can do this.

```
B = [(ligne[1], ligne[2]) for ligne.split() in file]
```

**Hint:**

Don't name a variable `B`. This looks like a class name or a constant.

**Edit:**

To access "the x of the sixth point in the table B" you will have to use

```
B[5][0]
```

`B` is a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the two columns I want to extract correspond to coordinates x and y. So when I ask for B[5,0], for instance, I want the x of the sixth point in the table B...But it does not work as well

Answer (score 0):

```
B = array([(ligne[1]),(ligne[2])])
```

This looks wrong.  Since `B` is an array, what you probably want is

```
B.append(array([(ligne[1]),(ligne[2])]))
```

B is now a list of arrays.  So `B[5,0]` should become `B[5][0]` -- Assuming you want the first entry on the 6th line of your file